# How to prevent closing of dialog when data updates fail

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I started playing with `ngDialog` but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the dialog from closing when an error ocurrs during data updates operations.

```
        ngDialog.openConfirm({
            scope: $scope,
            template: 'detailsTemplate'
        }).then(
            function () {
                //stop dialog when data insert fails
            },
            function () {
                //cancel clicked
            }
        );
```

This seems to me like it would be a very comon requirement for any application but none of the samples I seen address this problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you implement [catch and finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) on your promise to handle the error? I didn't see anything in the docs to disable the modal from being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put your AJAX logic?
You can manually close the dialog once AJAX is success, put your AJAX logic into dialog's Ctrl rather in the .then method.

Small example for your reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/3spbjpt8/3/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngDialog']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
        $scope.names = [];
    $scope.openDialog = function(){
        ngDialog.open({
        scope: $scope,
        template: 'templateForm',
        closeByDocument: false,
        controller: 'PopUpController'
      });
    }
});
myApp.controller('PopUpController', function($scope, ngDialog){
    $scope.cancel = function(){
    $scope.closeThisDialog();
  };
  $scope.submit = function(){
    $scope.disable = true;
    //AJAX logic can be put here
    $scope.names.push($scope.varName);

    //Do not call below sentence if AJAX is not success 
    $scope.closeThisDialog('cancel');


    $scope.disable = false;
  };
});
```